# How can I bump the package.json version and include it as a commit when a merge request is merged in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, package.json, git-merge, versioning, cicd

In my project, we bump the package.json version by patch each time a MR is merged into `develop`, our default branch.

Currently, we have added a CI/CD job that bumps the version, saves it as a commit and pushes it into the develop branch. This is working and it's being triggered **after** a MR is merged.

`gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
 - bump_version

bump-version:
  stage: bump_version
  script:
    - echo "Current version:"
    - cat package.json | grep "\"version\""
    - echo "Bumping version..."
    - ./bump_version_script.sh // Bumps version, git add, git commit, git push origin develop
    - echo "New version:"
    - cat package.json | grep "\"version\""
```

The bad thing about this is that our git history is being "contaminated" with those bump commits like this:

`$ git log --oneline`

```
* Bump version v1.0.3
* Merge branch 'C' into 'develop'
* Bump version v1.0.2
* Merge branch 'B' into 'develop'
* Bump version v1.0.1
* Merge branch 'A' into 'develop'
* Project init v1.0.0
```

Is there a way to bump the version and include it in the Merge commit? Thanks in advance.